# SSD as /tmp partition

Tags: ssd, cron, cloud, unionfs

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 server which has one drive where rootfs is mounted.

I just added an SSD disk which I have mounted at `/ssd`

Now I want my `/tmp` & `/var/tmp` to use this fast drive to speed up my server.  First I wish to tackle just `/tmp` (and I know repeated writes may shorten the life of ssd).

In my crontab, I wish to add an entry like this:

```
@reboot /bin/sleep 5; install -d -m 1777 /ssd/tmp 
&& install -d -m 1777 /tmp && rm -r /tmp && ln -s /ssd/tmp1 /tmp
```

the potentially superfluous `install -d -m 1777 /tmp`is only there to make sure that `rm -r /tmp` does not fail  (and `rm -r /tmp` exists to ensure that `ln -s` does not open another tmp under `/tmp` which will make this set ineffective.

Comment: I tried unionfs but wasn't able to make it work.

Comment: SSD disks get better and better, so I would not worry about the amount of writes. I would recommend some basic tuning (noatime, etc). Other than that every SSD should cope with it. Take a look here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80864/what-not-to-put-on-an-ssd/80868

Comment: I would put "root" (including /tmp and /var/tmp/ onto the ssd but not use crontab. Use `/etc/fstab` for it.

Comment: @Rinzwind May I suggest you post that as an answer?

Comment: The fastest `/tmp` would be on a tmpfs and then a swap partition on you SSD. Let a caching algorithm handle where to store your transient data because they're usually better at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply mount your ssd as /tmp partition. To mount on loading you can write this to /etc/fstab/.

For example:

```
$ cat /etc/fstab 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb2 during installation

...

/dev/sdb1 /tmp           ext4    discard,defaults        0       2
/dev/sdb2 /var/tmp       ext4    discard,defaults        0       2
```

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab for more information.

Comment: Tks @david and tks rinzwind.  What if I added the ssd as a swap and then add following to the /etc/fstab

`tmpfs    /tmp        tmpfs    defaults    0 0`
'tmpfs    /var/tmp    tmpfs    defaults   0 0`
`tmpfs    /run/shm    tmpfs    defaults    0 0`